# Place window relative to parent

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Ive got a simple modless dialog which I would like to place at the bottom right corner of the parent window. This is my first time working with windows forms in C (so please be patient if I don't directly understand).

I've tried positoning the window with [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but to no avail as the coordinates x and y are relative to the top left screen corner.

```
//hWnd is the parent window
hwndStatusBox = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_STATUSBOX), 
                             hWnd, svnStatusBoxProc); 

SetWindowPos(hwndStatusBox,NULL, 100, 100, 0, 0, 
             SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

Am I missing a function or do I have to calculate the offset myself?

I don't want to use the coordinates defined in the resource, i'd like to solve it programatically.

Comment: Someone downvoted without a comment, so I'll upvote to compensate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a top-level window, i.e. not a *child* window, the co-ordinates are indeed relative to the screen.

You will need to read the co-ordinates of the owning window, work out what offset you need, add on the offset and finally set the co-ordinates for your dialog, relative to the screen origin. Or you can call [`ClientToScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183434.aspx), passing `hWnd`, and get the system to do it for you.

Comment: The window I want to place is a child. Is it not possible to place it relativ to its parent?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679.aspx) says this about co-ordinates: "For a child window, x is the x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the window relative to the upper-left corner of the parent window's client area." In other words, what you are telling us does not seem consistent. I doubt it really is a child. Dialogs are top-level windows. They are not child windows.

Comment: Yes indeed I think I'm missing something :P
I added the code where I create the window, am I doing that right?

Comment: The call to CreateDialog looks fine to me. MSDN confuses things quite a bit by overloading the parameter named hwndParent. This is the *parent* window if you are creating a child window, or the *owner* window if you are creating a top-level window. You are doing the latter. The dialogs coords are screen relative.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation I did not know there was a difference. I set the WS_CHILD style in the resource and removed the WS_POPUP Style and now it works.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function to do this:

```
ClientToScreen
```

which converts a client coordinate to a screen coordinate. For example:-

```
message_box_position = {ParentWidth - MessageBoxWidth, ParentHeight - MessageBoxHeight}
ClientToScreen (parent_window_handle, &message_box_position)
SetWindowPos (message_box_handle, messahe_box_position)
```

Comment: -1 I'm trying to do the opposite. Please read the question thoroughly.

Comment: @R34lthing No, this is exactly what you are trying to do. You want to specify the coordinates relative to the client area of the owning window. But because you have a top-level dialog you have to specify screen relative coords. And `ClientToScreen` will perform that conversion. +1 to compensate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok I did not know that. I apologize for such a rash and inappropriate answer.

Comment: @R34lthing Feel free to rescind your down-vote and turn it into an up-vote